# Logical if always false on a servlet

Tags: java, string, servlets, equality, logical-operators

I am trying to get 3 parameters on my servlet,i split my code into 3 classes for code readability but on the `query_a1` method of my `DatabaseQuery` class i always get `false` and i cant understand why!
Here it is my servlets classes :

DatabaseQuery
    public class DatabaseQuery {

```
    //Query i aktivitetit 1
public static boolean query_a1(String user,String pass) {
    if (user== "andi" & pass=="andi")
        return true;
    else
        return  false;

}
//ky do te jete query i aktivitetit 2
public static void  query_a2() {

}
}
```

Servlet

```
  import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    @WebServlet("/web2")
    public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            //merr aktivitetitn nga i cili vijne parametrat
            int activiteti=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("activitetiNR").toString());

            //krijo nje switch per cdo parameter 
          switch (activiteti){
          case 1:{
              //marrim te dhenat qe i perkasin aktivitetit
              String user = req.getParameter("user").toString();
              System.out.println(user);
              String pass = req.getParameter("pass").toString();
            System.out.println(pass);

              //i kalojme ne metoden e klases Aktiviteti1 dhe marrim pergjigje dhe me pas japim response
            response(resp,Aktiviteti1.kontrolloDhenat(user,pass));
          }
          break;
          }
        }
        private void response(HttpServletResponse resp, String msg)
                throws IOException {
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println(msg);
        }
    }
```

Aktiviteti

```
public class Aktiviteti1 {
    //ketu vendosen kontrollet llogjike te aktivitetit 
public static String kontrolloDhenat(String user,String pass){
    //ndersa ketu therrasim queryn nga klasa database
if (DatabaseQuery.query_a1(user,pass)==true){

    return "Succes!";           
    }else{
        System.out.println(DatabaseQuery.query_a1(user,pass));
    return "Failure!";

    }
}
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are comparing `String` objects via `==` but as they are objects, they have to be compared as follows `string1.equals(string2)`
- You are using the *bitwise* AND operator (`&`) but the *logical* one (`&&`) has to be used here.

Here the corrected if statement:

```
if (user.equals("andi") && pass.equals("andi")) then {
    //foo
}
```

- See [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for further information about string comparison.
- See [Java Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for further information about operator usage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to revisit String comparison. The String comparison is done using `equals()` method not `==` operator. So below line is wrong. Further `&` is bitwise AND operator and for Logical AND you need to use `&&` operator.

```
if (user== "andi" & pass=="andi")
```

you should use

```
if (user.equals("andi") && pass.equals("andi"))
```

Comment: what a mistake i have done! thank you sir, it worked :)

Comment: All the best for your future work!!

Answer (score 1):

not use to compare string using `==` use `equals` .

Your code :
         if (user== "andi" & pass=="andi")
 write like :

```
    if(user.equals("andi")&&pass.equals("andi"))
```

if you want Ingore case`(like ANDI or Andi)` you should use like :

```
   if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("andi")&&pass.equalsIgnoreCase("andi"))
```